# VS Code and Git - How to managin code required for testing?

Tags: git, testing, visual-studio-code

What is the recommended way to manage code changes that I have to do only for testing?

I am commenting out code and adding in code only for testing purposes. E.g. Prod script will download files from S3 bucket but for testing I only want to grab the files on my local system.  Another example is disabling code that I don't want to run during testing such as deleting files after processing, or skipping different types of files.

I do manage different branches in git for features and development but I can't seem to figure out how to just make these changes in development and then not include them in a merge to master.

- Updated ...
  Another example is that I need to set a variable to save a file every hour.  But in testing I only want this to be every 2min.  When I write a  config file is it ok to do something like:

if LOCAL_Test = True:
SAVE_TABLE_DUR = 60
else:
SAVE_TABLE_DUR = 2

Thanks

Comment: that means your code is tightly coupled, if you can't mock parts of the code you have to rewrite the code so it can be tested without changes in the main code

Comment: Is there a way to manage this in vscode git?

Comment: I don't think Git is relevant here. If you need to make code changes for testing, that means you probably need to restructure your code so that those changes aren't necessary. This isn't something you manage with Git.

Comment: Read up on mocking in your testing framework, it you can't mock it means you use a different library to do the mocking. With mocking you can simulate all the stuff in the program that you are not testing

Comment: the tests should NOT be in a different branch in git, the tests test a piece a software and SHOULD be put in the same commit as the stuff that is under test

Comment: I think the  mocking might do the trick. I have to read more.  Thank you @rioV8.  One good example i have is that in local testing I just want to read files from disk instead of calling AWS queue.  In this case mocking makes sense.  The other option is that I have a second config file.  This helps in scenarios such as different logfile location, etc.

Comment: if done correct you can also mock settings or mock the file that need to be read, make the mock function a decorator of the actual function and change/force the arguments if needed